# How to validate if the browser supports HTML attribute Required through javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, required

I am currently working on the validation of my forms. I think that the best way is with the `Required` html attribute, since it is simple and indicates to the user the first input that is not checked.

The issue is that `Required` is not supported by older browsers, so I generated a code in pure javascript to make the validation.

The problem is that validating through javascript loses the characteristic offered by the `Required` of pointing where there are inputs without checked.

Therefore I would like to know if there is any way through javascript (pure) to know if the browser supports the html `Required` attribute, so I can only activate the validation with javascript if `Required` is not supported.

Comment: could you post the code ?

Comment: The only browsers you're likely to encounter that doesn't support it is IE older than 11. I don't think there's any specific feature test for this, so just check the browser version.

Comment: See https://html5-tutorial.net/form-validation/polyfills-for-form-validation/

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works

```
  var input = document.getElementById('inputid');
    if (typeof input.required != "undefined") {
        alert('has support');
    }
```